# How to insert information into pdb file?

Tags: c++, debugging, portable-executable, pdb-files

I am writing a small debugger for some trace work. I want to tell my debugger some information like mark some functions not to set breakpoint in those functions. I think I can put this information into .data section or pdb file. Can anyone help me about how to do that work?

Answer (score 0):

The PDB file format is documented by Microsoft here: https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb

It is also documented by the LLVM infrastructure team here: https://llvm.org/docs/PDB/index.html